# "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported." error while trying to do mean encoding

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen many topics about this error but I can't find one that is relative to my problem (if there is one, i'm sorry).

I got a dataframe, with one target variable and several explicative variables like hours, day, month, etc....

I'm trying to add columns, with the mean value of those explicative variables.

For example, in the "hour_mean" column I want the mean value of my target variable at 1 am if it's 1 am, the mean value at 2 am if it's 2 am, and so on.

I have found a way to do this by using this kind of code :

```
df['mean_month']=""
for j in range (len(df)):
    
    for i in range(1,12):
        if df['month'][j]==i :
            df['mean_month'][j]=(df.loc[df['month']==i])["target_variable"].mean()
```

It's effective but it's taking a lot of time to process (I got 3 years of data, one row per hour) and I get this warning : *"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy%22)*

So I tried to find a "sexiest" way to do it and tried this :

```
df['mean_month']=""
for j in range (len(df)):
    
    for i in range(1,12):
        if df['month'][j]==i :
            df['mean_month'][j]=(df.loc[:,('month'==i,"target_variable")]).mean()
```

And I get the following error message : *KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index([False], dtype='object'). See [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike%22)*

I don't really understand what I should change to avoid this and have a "clean" way to do what I want.

May be I'm doing it the wrong way, and if you have any idea I'll be glad to hear them!

Have a nice day all

edit : here is the look at df.head() as asked
[image]

Comment: Update your post with the output of `df.head()`, please?

Comment: I added a screen